# Find DFT of $f(m,n)=0.5\cdot\left((-1)^{m+n}+1\right)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, image-processing

I was trying to solve the following question:

> Consider an image $8\times 8$ so:
> $$
> f(m,n)=0.5\cdot\left((-1)^{m+n}+1\right)
> $$
> Find the DFT of the image.

In the solution they did: (sorry in advanced for it being a picture)

> [image]

I don't understand how they got from $0.5\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\exp(-i2\pi (um+vn)/8)$ to $0.5\cdot 8^2\delta(u,v)$. I'm studying from the "Gonzalez & Woods image processing" book so the definition there of the $\delta$ function is (Dirac delta function):
$$
\delta(t,z)=\begin{cases}
\infty & t=z=0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
How did they got to $0.5\cdot 8^2\delta(u,v)$? What is the property of $\delta$ did they use?

It looks like the formula is:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-i2\pi\left(\frac{\left(k-x\right)}{M}m+\frac{\left(l-x\right)}{N}n\right)}=MN\cdot\delta(k-x,l-x)
$$
Is it correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

This image is like a checkerboard
alternating 0 and 1.

The DFT in this particular case
can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
F[u,v] 
&=& 
\sum_{p,q=0}^3
\exp
\left[
-2\pi j \frac{2pu+2qv}{8}
\right]
+
\sum_{p,q=0}^3
\exp
\left[
-2\pi j \frac{(2p+1)u+(2q+1)v}{8}
\right] \\
&=&
\left[
1+
\exp
\left(
-2\pi j \frac{u+v}{8}
\right)
\right]
G[u,v]
\tag{*}
\end{eqnarray*}
where
$$
G[u,v]
=
\sum_{p,q=0}^3
\exp
\left[
-2\pi j \frac{pu+qv}{4}
\right]
$$

The G term in (*) is the DFT of a constant $4\times 4$ image.
It is thus equal to 16 for
$u=0,v=0$ and also
by periodicity for 3 other pairs
$(0,4),(4,0),(4,4)$ and zero otherwise.

The first term in (*) is null for the pairs
$(0,4),(4,0)$ and equal to 2 for the pairs
$(0,0),(4,4)$.

The DFT value is 32 for the pairs
$(0,0),(4,4)$.

Comment: But where is $\delta$? I'm trying to get the same solution as they got.

Comment: $\delta$ means indicator function you have a $\delta$ in $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$. This is identical to their results.